# trying to use npm start after creating react app returns error

Tags: reactjs, npm, webpack

whenever i create a react app and try to start it I get this error

```
There might be a problem with the project dependency tree.
It is likely not a bug in Create React App, but something you need to fix locally.

The react-scripts package provided by Create React App requires a dependency:

  "webpack": "4.41.5"

Don't try to install it manually: your package manager does it automatically.
However, a different version of webpack was detected higher up in the tree:

  C:\Users\david\node_modules\webpack (version: 4.41.0)

Manually installing incompatible versions is known to cause hard-to-debug issues.

If you would prefer to ignore this check, add SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK=true to a(n) .env file in your project.
That will permanently disable this message but you might encounter other issues.
```

my current solution is to add the `SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK=true` to a .env file but I would like to fix this issue universally so I don't have to do that for every react app I create.

the error is longer than what I have posted and it gives suggestions on how to fix for that specific react app but none of the solutions work

here is the package.json

```
{
  "name": "dev-chat",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.4.1",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.2.1",
    "react": "^16.13.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.0",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: I'd give a global install a try. `npm install -g webpack@4.41.5`

Comment: Please provide your `package.json` file.

Comment: @stackoverflow-newbie 

the error is longer than what I have posted and it gives suggestions on how to fix for that specific react app but none of the solutions work

Comment: Uninstall the global version.

Comment: @crashmstr can you elaborate?

Comment: @davidsnyder "a different version of webpack was detected higher up in the tree" indicates that you either globally installed webpack or that you've created a new project in a sub-folder where you have another project that has webpack installed. Either uninstall the global version or do not nest your react projects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've seen this before in one of my projects, this error sometimes means you are installing a react app inside of another react app (that has a different webpack version)

Because I see your node_modules install path is within the users folder of your system's root. You have likely created the react app at an unintentional directory.

Remove the react app you have created in C:\Users\david, and reinstall it in another directory like C:\Users\david\desktop, by running a command like: `npx create-react-app [YOUR PROJECT NAME]` (for the project name remove the square brackets).